# Why does Android allow reading files without permission?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-file, android-storage

In my app, I wrote the following code to access files:

```
public void performFileSearch() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);

    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    intent.setType("image/*");

    startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

In `onActivityResult` I am receiving `Uri` of the selected image.

Why am I able to access the `Uri` without having `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission?

`minSdk = 19`

`compileSdk = 27`

`targetSdk = 27`

Test Android Versions:

`Android 4.4.2 API 19`

`Android 6.0.1 API 23`

Comment: in which android OS version your app is running

Comment: I tested it on `Android 6.0.1` and `Android 4.4.2`

Comment: What is your compile SDK version?

Comment: The runtime permission is needed from api >=23 and below marshmallow all permission are granted at the time of app installation

Comment: Agreed with @NileshRathod  check your permission in application properties.

Comment: compile SDK is 27

Comment: Did you add in your manifest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>. It means strict permission. Only notify, during the time of install.

Comment: @InsaneCat in the application settings  no permission is granted.

Comment: @arifulislamarif I did not add any of those permission and I am still able to get the URI and read/display/upload the selected image.

Comment: Regarding `compileSdkVersion` - it's not relevant for the behavior of the app. What matters is the `targetSdkVersion`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why am I able to access the Uri without having READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Because the user was involved in choosing it. You are granted temporary access to that document (and, if you use `takePersistableUriPermissions()`), you can have durable access to that document.

Comment: Is this for all Android versions? Are there any exceptions?

Comment: @malhobayyeb: "Is this for all Android versions?" -- for the versions that have `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, yes. That was added in Android 4.4. "Are there exceptions?" -- none that I know of.